# Проблема с flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть такая проблема с `flex-wrap`.

В контейнере у меня 3 блока, в маленьком разрешении экрана надо что бы центральный блок был первым.

Есть способ добиться этого только с помощью `flex`, без использования `js`?

Вот сам пример:

```css
/* Common Styles */
.content {
    color: #fff;
    font: 100 24px/100px sans-serif;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.content div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
.red {
    background: orangered;
}
.green {
    background: yellowgreen;
}
.blue {
    background: steelblue;
}

/* Flexbox Styles */
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.content1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.content2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="red">1</div>
  <div class="green">2</div>
  <div class="blue">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .green {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что хотел.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, не за что, желаю успехов!